# how to divide iPad screen into 4 equal parts?

Tags: swift

I'm planning on making a new app that would require the iPad screen to be divided into 4 equal parts and have a list in each part, but I cannot figure out a way to do so. 
something similar to what I want to do is UISplitViewController, but I want the screen to be in 4 sections and I don't want to have any one of them as the root view controller. 
cheers!

Comment: Use 4 views despite this is not the right way to do things.

Comment: You can make one root view controller and add horizontal stack view with four equally distributed containers.

Comment: @gasho could you explain again how that would work?

Comment: @user3344236 then how should I do it?

Comment: Open the storyboard file and add a horizontal stack view. Then add four container views to the stack view and connect a view controller to each of them. You will figure it out yourself when you are in the process of implementing it. good luck

Answer (score 0):

Use a **UICollectionViewController** and make its frame equals the size of the screen, then implement a **UITableViewController** for the cells. Assuming you already know about reusableCells.